# The importance of positive GPA trends in PhD admissions?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, gpa

For admission committees, how important are the (upward) trends in your GPA and how much will it remedy lackluster performance in the past?

Background: I'm an international CS applicant with an overall undergraduate GPA of around 2.8 with a GPA of 3.5 in the last two years (undergrad took 5 years total). I'm also finishing my masters with a 4.0 GPA. Considering these facts, how much should I expect my overall undergraduate GPA to hurt my chances for Ph.D. admission in the US/Canada?

(I'm aware of other factors such as recommendations, GRE and research experience. However, I would like to keep this question specific to the effect of positive GPA trends vs. overall GPA)

P.S: I have looked at seemingly similar questions/answers on the site but none of them cover this specific question.

Comment: If your GPA is below the threshold the admissions office is looking for, it doesn't hurt to point out any extenuating circumstances that may apply.

Comment: If your undergraduate GPA is below the threshold that the university requires, it's possible that nobody will even see your application, and in particular, nobody will read about your extenuating circumstances.

Comment: Grades in the first two years of undergraduate don't weigh very heavily, from what I'm seen.

Comment: Thank you J.R, JeffE and aparante001 for your insights :)